# Firestore Subcollection Not Loading On Redux

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, redux-toolkit

I am having an issue with Redux Toolkit not updating it's state for Firestore DB Subcollections. The Firebase Authentication fields work as Redux does update the userId, firstName(displayName), and email fields however the title and email fields which are from Firestore are not being updated. Any thoughts? Greatly appreciate it!

Please see below:

```js
//App.js

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    getAuth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      try {
        const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid)
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef)
        if (user && docSnap.exists()) {
          const data = docSnap.data()
          console.log(user.uid, user.email, user.displayName, data.lastname, data.title)
          console.log(data) // {lastname: 'sparrow', title: 'pirate'}
          dispatch(loginUser({
            userId: user.uid,
            firstName: user.displayName,
            lastName: data.lastname, //not loading to redux state
            title: data.title, // not loading to redux state
            email: user.email
          }))
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.code)
      }
      }
    )})

//redux

const initialState = {
    userId: null,
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    title: null,
    email: null,
}

const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "user",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        loginUser: (state, action) => {
            state.userId = action.payload.userId
            state.firstName = action.payload.firstName
            state.lastName = action.payload.lastName
            state.title = action.payload.title
            state.email = action.payload.email
        },
        logoutUser: (state) => {
            state.userId = null
            state.firstName = null
            state.lastName = null
            state.title = null
            state.email = null
        },
    }
})

export const { loginUser, logoutUser } = userSlice.actions
export default userSlice.reducer
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: HI does my posted answer help? If then acknowledge it, if not then we can solve further.

Comment: Hi Rohit, it seems like my code was fine after all. I believe there was an issue with my Redux Chrome Extension tool which was not recording all of the state fields. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: I have updated my answer with adding the chrome Redux DevTools to check whether it is updating the state correctly or not.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [**Create a Redux State Slice**](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start#create-a-redux-state-slice) documentations from **Redux Toolkit** you also have to export  each slice function as a `userSlice.actions` along with `userSlice.reducer` then Add the slice reducer to the store as follows :

**features/user/userSlice.js**

```
import {
    createSlice
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
const initialState = {
    userId: null,
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    title: null,
    email: null,
}
const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "user",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        loginUser: (state, action) => {
            const {
                userId,
                firstName,
                lastName,
                title,
                email
            } = action.payload;
            return {
                ...state,
                userId,
                firstName,
                lastName,
                title,
                email
            };
        },
        logoutUser: (state) => {
            state.userId = null
            state.firstName = null
            state.lastName = null
            state.title = null
            state.email = null
        },
    }
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const {
    loginUser,
    logoutUser
} = userSlice.actions
export default userSlice.reducer
```

**app/store.js** :

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import userReducer from '../features/user/userSlice'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
  },
})
```

Then use the Redux State and Actions in React Components just how you are using it.
As you have said that you are getting firestore data of `lastname` and `title` as intended.

But just for confirming you can also send those like this so if in case those fields happen to be null.

```
const loginUserAction = {
          userId: user.uid,
          firstName: user.displayName,
          lastName: data.lastname || "", // ⇐ 
          title: data.title || "", // ⇐ 
          email: user.email
        }
        dispatch(loginUserAction)
```

**Update**: Also check the Redux chrome extension to observe whether the states are updated or not.

Reference : [**Redux Toolkit Quick Start**](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I actually had these already included for my Redux. I just left them out. As mentioned, the authentication (Firebase Auth) is being retrieved from Redux but not the database (Firestore DB).

Comment: Just wanted to make an update: It's odd but today I tried out the code and it works. This may have been an issue with the Redux Chrome extension as all data is now being loaded into my Redux user initialState.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you.